# getIntent returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

I have came across a lot of questions similar to this, But I'm unable to solve it, Even though i'm doing it in the right way .

I'm sending the String in this way :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("APP_PACKAGE_EXTRAS", "com.facebook.katana");

        if (null != intent) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

I'm receiving it using this way :

```
        Intent IntentExtras = getIntent();
        String Package = IntentExtras.getExtras().getString("APP_PACKAGE_EXTRAS");
```

I'm getting NPE, Why ?

Comment: Where you are calling the method getIntent() ?

Comment: can you share the code from where you are calling the activity

Comment: There is very little code here, please share more.

Comment: Isn't that what should i do ?, The first code shows where i'm calling/starting it .

Comment: That's literally the whole code, Simple app includes 2 activities, One has a button, which send the String, and open another activity, and i'm receiving it in the code 2 .

Comment: which line the error pointed to ?

Comment: to the getString line .

Comment: where you put the  `String` ? Inside `onCreate` method ?

Comment: Yes. But the activity isn't the "main" one, And i added " if intent !=null " statement .

Comment: Do you have this code "Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);" inside onclick view? If yes means, 'this' will not contains the Activity Context. Instead you can do new "Intent(ActivityName.this,MainActivity.class)"

Comment: @KartihkrajDuraisamy good point, but the issue is this code will not even compile, in case sending `OnClickListener` instead of `Context` to the `Intent` constructor, right?

Comment: @Yazan: That's worst from me. Thanks for pointing out early. Exactly it will not compile at all...

Comment: Did the problem solved ?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
  Intent intentExtras = getIntent();
        String Package = intentExtras.getStringExtra("APP_PACKAGE_EXTRAS");
```

instead of

```
  Intent IntentExtras = getIntent();
        String Package = IntentExtras.getExtras().getString("APP_PACKAGE_EXTRAS");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("a", "b");
startActivity(i);
```

In your second activity:

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("a");
```

Comment: result : text == b , fine explanation, works simply !

Answer (score 0):

**Sender**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("APP_PACKAGE_EXTRAS", "com.facebook.katana");
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiver**

String Package;

Inside `OnCreate` method

```
Package=getIntent().getExtras().getString("APP_PACKAGE_EXTRAS");
```

**Edited in Receiver**

```
  if(intent.getExtras() == null) {

       Log.e("null",null);

    } else {

   Package=getIntent().getExtras().getString("APP_PACKAGE_EXTRAS");

    Log.e("Package", Package);

    }
```

Comment: It's still the same, the problem in getting the intent .

Comment: check again and see what does the log display

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

To set value in Intent's extended data (This should be right way to use for name of the extra data 'packagePrefix.dataName')

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity.class);
  intent.putExtra("com.google.exampleapp.KeyName", value);
```

To retrieve values from Intent's extended data

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
            messageCount = extras.getString("com.google.exampleapp.KeyName");
    }
```